# Default value should not be removed even if Truncating table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `registration` table, in which I stored details of `super admin` and `admin` and other users also. my question is even If I perform a truncate operation on that table, still, the `super admin` and `admin` entries should not be removed. It has to be there always as a default entry.

Here is my registration table.

[image: Registration Table]

So, I want to freeze the entry of `super admin` and `admin` with the ID and password and It should not be changed.
Even if I am making a new database at that time also I didn't want to do manual entries for the same.

[Stored procedure I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkkPX.png)

Comment: Truncate has no such option, what's the problem with DELETE?

Comment: @P.Salmon Probably the OP doesn't want to trigger an implicit COMMIT from TRUNCATE . Or maybe the OP intends to reset everything except the  said 2 rows , but DELETE still retain certain data such as current auto increment value which is commonly used for ID .

Comment: @blabla_bingo yes you are right I want to truncate to maintain auto-increment values of ID.

Comment: In this case, you have to check if the admin and super admin has the lowest id  , as the auto increment attribute only increases from the highest numeric value currently existing.   For instance, if your admin has an ID 1 and super admin has and ID 5, then the next auto increment value will be 6, leaving the gap 2,3,4 open . If you want the ID values to be sequential, I'm afraid you have to  manually define the ID values to bridge the gap.  After that, use auto increment .

Comment: @blabla_bingo, yes ID for admin and super admin to be fixed as 1 and 2 as shown in Image.

Comment: @blabla_bingo I tried your suggested stored procedure. but It gives me an error.  I am attaching a screenshot in my original question, can you please check.

Comment: @Helly Soni That's weird. I wrote and tested it in workbench. I have added some test data in the answer for you to try.  By the way, my page has trouble depicting the image. Would you please paste the error code for me ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo it is working in workbench, actually, I am trying in PhpMyAdmin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to truncate and still retain certain line, use a temporary table to keep the rows intended to stay. Then insert them back to the registration table. This can be done in a procedure. My apologies in advance as my page has trouble displaying the image so the base table name and all its column names are purely based on assumptions.

```
create table registration (id int primary key auto_increment,user varchar(20));
insert registration (user) values ('admin'),('root'),('super admin');
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists truncate_reg//
create procedure truncate_reg()
begin
drop temporary table if exists temp_registration;
create temporary table temp_registration select * from registration where user='admin' or user='super admin';
truncate registration ;
insert registration select * from temp_registration;

end//
delimiter ;
call truncate_reg;
select * from registration;
-- result:
1, admin
3, super admin
```